# json condition to get only one val of an object

Tags: json

I am trying to get one particular song in a json array object based on the ID of that song.  My json file appears like this...

file name "playlist.json"...

```
 "song": [
       {
           "songTitle": "Song Title 01",
           "songDesc": "This is the description",
           "songUrl": "./music/sample.mp3",
           "ID": 1
       },
       {
           "songTitle": "Song Title 02",
           "songDesc": "This is the description",
           "songUrl": "./music/sample.mp3",
           "ID": 2
       }
]
```

Please note, there are other objects in the json file.  This one is just the list of songs.

I have tried doing this and just keep coming up with errors.  I can get the contents of a row but can't figure out how to only get the contents of a specific row with the ID of 1.

```
$(function() {
$.getJSON('playlist.json', function(data) {
$.each(data.song, function(i, f) {
if (f.ID == 1) {
var currentStation = f.songUrl
}
});});});
```

As you can see, I obviously have no idea what I am doing.  I just want to return the song URL of a row who has ID = 1 and then make that song URL the currentStation variable.

Please help.

Comment: Your example seems to work fine for me, are you getting any console errors? and is your `playlist.json` start and end with `{` and `}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var currentStation; 


$(function() {
   $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/playlist.json', function(data) {

        var songs = data["song"];

        for( var song_key in songs){  // Looping through songs by associating song to each javascript object found in the array.
            if(songs[song_key]["ID"] == 1){
                currentStation = songs[song_key]["songUrl"];
            }
        }
        console.log(currentStation);
    });
});
```

Comment: I was optimistic... but it's still not working for some reason.

Comment: test.php:57 Uncaught ReferenceError: currentStation is not defined(…)

This is in a line that displays the <audio> tags where the source is the currentStation definition...

<script>
document.write('<audio id="aud" src="' + currentStation + '" controls></audio>');
</script>

Comment: Could this be because the player is being created before the definition is taking place?

Comment: Please see my edited answer - i made a few mistakes when accessing attributes of each JSON object.

Comment: Note: I have used an absolute url when requesting for the json code. You don't need to though.

Comment: Really confused as to why it's not working now because the console log is showing that the currentStation was set fine.  But it's still not working in the player itself.  However, for testing, if I just set the songUrl manually with a var = url then it works.  So I don't know.  And no errors in the console log on this particular action.  So maybe something ise out of order.

Comment: Can you post your full html and js code along with a full stacktrace? It's a little bit hard to understand what's going on your side.

Comment: To be fair, you did manage to get the variable set properly according to the console log.  I think it's simply a matter of the player creation timing.  I have some workarounds for that.  I will go ahead and mark this as best answer when it lets me.  It would be difficult to post the entire code on here or even jsfiddle or something because it is in so many sections being included with PHP include commands and stuff.  Thank you.